# What statistical test do I use for differences in proportions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, genetics

I have two groups of samples with a proportion of mutations in each sample being a particular type (the proportions are represented as a fraction of 1). How to I check if that type of mutation is significantly likelier to happen in one group over the other?

Comment: You could use a $\chi^2$ test for proportions.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-square-test-and-test-of-equal-proportions?rq=1

Comment: If you want to be able to consider both one- and two- tailed tests, what about a two-sample proportions test?

Comment: Possible dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286663/chi-square-test-or-z-test-for-comparing-two-proportions, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234010/2-sample-proportions-z-test-vs-fishers-exact-test, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284718/test-for-proportion-difference-vs-test-for-odds-ratios, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-squared-test-and-test-of-equal-proportion

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

You could use a χ2 test for proportions. – user25658
If you want to be able to consider both one- and two- tailed tests, what about a two-sample proportions test? – Glen_b

See also  [What is the relationship between a chi squared test and test of equal proportions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-squared-test-and-test-of-equal-proportion?rq=1)