# Chi-square test or Z-test for comparing two proportions?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution, proportion

On [this website](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268) the appropriate statistical test for comparing two independent proportions is described as a **$Z$-test** (a normal distribution is used to obtain a $p$-value).

However, in R `prop.test`, a **Chi-square** distribution is invoked to obtain the $p$-value comparing two independent proportions.

An R example is:

```
prop.test(x = c(474, 376), n = c(750, 750))
```

I was wondering how a Chi-square based approach comparing two independent proportions works (e.g., *is the test a chi-square test or a different test that produces a statistic that follows a Chi-square distribution*) and how it compares with the Z-test approach (e.g., *in terms of accuracy and power*) discussed [on that website](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/268)?

Comment: If you check `prop.test`, `chisq.test` and z-test on your data then they all give you the same p-value = 3.285e-07. All tests should be conducted without continuity correction.

Comment: The chi-square statistic is the square of the z-statistic. They both relate to the *one* degree of freedom in the outcome, which is basically related to a single variable that is approximately Gaussian distributed. I wouldn't be surprised that you can convert the two statistics in one or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat:  This is my non-statistician view of the question.

The following website discusses the two approaches. The `prop.test` approach is the statistically fundamental one. The *z-test* approach is, in my eyes, an approximation of this, and relies on certain assumptions about the data.

[www.r-bloggers.com/comparison-of-two-proportions-parametric-z-test-and-non-parametric-chi-squared-methods/](https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparison-of-two-proportions-parametric-z-test-and-non-parametric-chi-squared-methods/)

Since R has good support for tests of proportions (confidence intervals, `binom.test`, `multinomial.test`), I don't see why one would want to use the *z-test* approach. But that may just be my bias and particular education.

Considering using confidence intervals in R, the following two pages have examples of confidence intervals for proportions, `binom.test`, and `multinomial.test` in R. (Caveat: I am the author of these two webpages.)

[rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html)

[rcompanion.org/handbook/H_02.html](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_02.html)