What is the ideal hypothesis test for Bernoulli random variables?
If you have a two table tennis ball outputting machines acting as Bernoulli trials. The first machine gives a player 1000 balls with p=0.7 of being red and 0.3 yellow. The second gives a player 100 balls with an unknown probability of the Bernoulli. What hypothesis tests can be done to check the similarity of distributions between the first and second machine?
How would the test be different if the first machine generates 1000 balls at random them the second machine generates 100 of the 1000 balls and you want to know how likely is it the second machine to create a subsample representative of the first machine sample?

There are many different tests for single binomial distributed variables or comparisons of two binomial distributed variables, with different advantages and disadvantages. Asking for the ideal one is not an objective question.

I have given an example in the question body. In this case, which tets would you apply?

Your example only specifies the size of the observations. To decide on a particular test it is also necessary to have meta data in order to decide about the different tests thay can be applied, each with different advantages and disadvantages. There is already a large body of literature discussing them. There is no clear simple short answer.

What does it mean that a hypothesis test is the 'ideal' hypothesis test?

Is this really a question about tennis ball machines? If you would explain the real underlying problem more accurately, then possibly arguments about the 'ideal hypothesis test' could be given that relate to the actual example.

The 2 variables in the OP's question are in fact binomial, not Bernoulli (they are counts from a Bernoulli process). So to compare the 2 machines (first part of the question), one needs to compare 2 Binomial variables, and one can do this with a 2x2 contingency table, using a Fisher-exact, or $\chi^2$ test.
The 2nd part of the question (if I understand it correctly) has the 2nd machine sampling 100 balls (w/o replacement?) from the 1000 which were output by the 1st machine. And the OP asks how can we test that the subsample's proportions are "close" to the original sample? The issue here is that the 2 variables are no longer independent, and that the 2nd machine no longer follows a Binomial distribution, and but a Hypergeometric one.
You should be able to still use a $\chi^2$ test, but now the squared differences are not to the *expectations under the null", but directly between the first machines's proportions, and the second's (to see how well the 2nd machine mimics the first one, i.e. how "representative the random subsampling is).
Alternatively you could use a confidence interval for the hypergeometric distribution: see this post on CV, with references and code for how to do it.
In the first case, a significant result will tell you that the 2 machines do not follow the same underlying Bernoulli process. In the 2nd case, a significant result would be a "false positive", i.e. an "anomalous" sub-sample.
Note that in this specific case ($n_1=1000, p=.7, n_2=100$), the Binomial or Hypergeometric distributions are very well approximated by normal distributions.

If they are approximated can a T test be used?

For the 2nd scenario, yes, you could (after all, the $\chi^2$ test is just a z-test...)

But why? Does the t test not test the MEAN of CONTINUOUS variables? Can it really be applied to dichotomous variables?  Can a Chi square and t test yield the same result?

Because, by definition of the $\chi^2$ distribution with $\nu$ d.o.f., itis the sum of $\nu$ $z^2$ distributions. In your case, the d.o.f. is 1, so $chi^2$ test is a z test (will give you exactly the same p-value). As to why a test for continuous variables can be used to test discrete variables, this is an asymptotic property, which was first estab;ished by De Moivre and Laplace. See wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution.

Ok, but if this test (proposed by a fellow) is published in an article the question will still remain why did you just not used a Chi-sq goodness of fit test? What would be the answer? In what scenario can it not be interchanegable?

Indeed. That is why I did noty mention a z-test earlier (why explain things to a reviewer/reader, when you can spare yourself the explanatrion by using a $\chi^2$ test. And it is not a question of interchangeability, it is a matrhematical fact that the distribution of a $chi^2$ with 1 d.o.f is exactly identical to the distribution of a $z^2$. So the tests will return exactly the same p-value (and the z-statistics will be exactly the square root of the $chi^2$ statistic. Check this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286663/chi-square-test-or-z-test-for-comparing-two-proportions

Is this only a 1 d.o.f case? So if the values were 1,2,3 a chi square would be the only choice yes?

Correct: $\chi^2$ is the exact same as z-test only for 1 d.o.f. Beyond that, $\chi^2$ is the only valid choice.

Your best estimate of the probability is:
$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{100}(X_1 + \ldots + X_{100})$
From the CLT:
$\hat{p} \sim N(\mu = p_{100}, \sigma= \frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}) $
So your 95% confidence interval is $[\hat{p} - \frac{1.96}{10}, \hat{p} + \frac{1.96}{10}]$
If $0.70 \notin [\hat{p} - \frac{1.96}{10}, \hat{p} + \frac{1.96}{10}]$, then you can reject the hypothesis $p_{1000} = p_{100}$ at a significance level that is less than 5%.
So for your second question,
$\hat{p} \sim N(\mu = \bar{p}_{1000}, \sigma= 0.10) $
and
$\bar{p}_{1000} \sim N(\mu = p_{1000}, \sigma = 0.031)$
This can be modeled as
$\hat{p} = \bar{p}_{1000} + \epsilon_1 = (p_{1000} + \epsilon_2) + \epsilon_1$
where
$\epsilon_1 \sim N(0, .1), \: \epsilon_2 \sim N(0, .031)$
$\implies \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 \sim N(0, \sqrt{0.031^2 + 0.10^2})$
$\implies \hat{p} \sim N(p_{1000}, 0.104)$
For extended reading on this topic, I recommend pages 92-95 and 150-159 of All of Statistics.
