# When to use Chi-squared and when Z test for categorical variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion, z-test

The problem is:

> There was a survey conducted among 1137 adults from California, Nevada, and Oregon. They
>   were chosen randomly and they answered to the following question “Do you think Marijuana
>   should be legalized? Below is the summary of responses.

```
Answer/Region Calfornian Nevadan Oregonian
Should               264      299     351
Should not           38       55      77
Don't know/No answer 16       15      22
Total                318      369     450
```

- a. Conduct an appropriate hypothesis test evaluating whether there is a difference in the
  proportion of Californian and Nevadan who think Marijuana should be legalized.
- b. Calculate a 95% confidence interval for the difference between the proportions of
  Californian and Nevadan who think Marijuana should be legalized and interpret it in the
  context of the data.
- c. The conclusion of the test in part (a) may be incorrect, meaning a testing error was made.
  If an error was made, was it a Type 1 or a Type 2 Error? Explain.

---

I know how to use normal distribution to calculate the `p-value` for two binary variables. It is my solution:

$$p ̂_{pool}=(264+299)/(316+369)=0.821$$

$$H_0:p ̂_c-p ̂_n=0 \\
H_1:p ̂_c-p ̂_n≠0 \\
SE=\sqrt{(0.82*0.18)/316+(0.82*0.18)/369}=0.03 \\
p ̂_c-p ̂_n=0.83-0.81=0.02 \\
z=(0.02-0)/0.03=0.66 \\
P(Z<z)+P(Z>z)≈0.51⇒ \text{Fail to Reject } H_0$$

For (b), I use a similar apporach but I use $p ̂_c$ nad $p ̂_n$ instead of $p ̂_{pool}$ to calculate $SE$. For (c), I think it's Type II error because we "failed to reject H0".

However, I suspect if I had to use Chi-squared for this problem because I have three columns. Could you please guide me if my solution is correct and when to use this solution and when Chi-squired. Could both approach be applicable here?

Comment: If you have a normal random variable $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, then $X^2$ is $\chi^2_1$ distributed. Thus the $\chi^2$ and $z$-test are essentially the same. See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-squared-test-and-test-of-equal-proportion?noredirect=1&lq=1